# Chrome only displays webpages in -nosandbox and in safe mode

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, webpage

As title. Nothing displays on Chrome.
Not even settings, extensions, incognito mode. Only about:blank seem to not give me the oops error.
Things that I have tried:

1. Reinstall Chrome
2. Disabled all antivirus/malware protection
3. Tried Chrome Canary
4. Chrome repair tool as suggest by support showed no issues
5. Malware byte - No malware detected
6. Spybot search and destroy - Nothing detected
7. Hardware acceleration turned off
8. Cache cleared

Comment: What extensions have you got running?
Click the top right (3 dots) context menu and go to Settings, then Extensions tab on the left.

Comment: The extensions tab doesn't work. when I'm running it through windows safe mode and through -no-sandbox I only have Adobe Acrobat running